# Getting no $_POST data (PHP 7.1/Debian 8) LAMP problems

Tags: php, post, server, apache2

I have a script coded, I coded it at xampp and it was working. So its at localhost working but I tried to setup this server at Ubuntu, Debian, nothing worked.

Its like that:

index.php:

```
switch ($_GET["page"]) {
case ("firstpage"):
  include ("firstpage.php");

  break;

case ("secondpage"):
print_r($_POST);
  break;
```

index.php?page=firstpage / better said firstpage.php

```
<form action="index.php?page=secondpage" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="test1">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and if I do this with my virtual server (Debian 8, LAMP installed, PHP 7.1, apache2 Header modules activated) then there is a empty array.

If I do it via xampp (Mac OS X) their is then the output coming..

What is the problem? Somebody can help me via TeamViewer or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Put a `var_dump($_GET, $_POST);` at the very beginning of the script (outside of any switch and other conditionals), and see what you get. I am not aware if anything has changed in regard to this with PHP 7, but if it doesn’t allow for accessing GET values from the URL on a POST request any more, then you can also put the page name into a hidden form field instead of inside the form action, and then evaluate `$_REQUEST["page"]` to decide which file to include.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I tried also with PHP5.. Im currently also trying with PHP5

Answer (score 0):

You can try a workaround. Instead passing your number page in the url, you can send it throught a hidden button.

index.php

```
if(isset($_POST['page'])){
    if($_POST['page'] == 'firstpage'){
        include ("firstpage.php");
    }elseif($_POST['page'] == 'secondpage'){
        //second page
    }
}else{
//$_POST['page'] is missing
}
```

and the form

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test1">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="secondpage">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```